# Where can I find a previously installed application in linux? Preparing for an upgrade

Tags: linux, installation, make

I'm currently trying to update my duo_security application that I installed 4 years ago. I'm following the instructions, but I hit a roadblock when it says:

**Note: You'll need to use the same --prefix as when you originally installed the app.**

Now the question is how do I find out where was this was originally installed to use as the prefix variable?

And one final question, when you do a **sudo make install**, does this install actually copy files all over the system like how windows does it? Or does it just stay in the current directory of the install?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file for the ForceCommand directive for login_duo. My handbuilt system shows

```
ForceCommand /usr/local/sbin/login_duo
```

so the `--prefix` was `/usr/local` which is I think the default, what comes before the `/sbin/login_duo` will be the prefix.

When you make install it will overwrite the files except those noted.

For some distros Duo now supply repos or pre-built packages. It may be worth removing your current installation and switching to one of these if available.

Comment: what is the directory sbin for? ... ok i looked at my sshd file and it shows "ForceCommand /usr/sbin/login_duo" --- so i would use --prefix=/usr  ?